# Delphi, Working around Google Play Console's "Design your app for tablets" optimization tip

Tags: android, delphi, google-play

After uploading an app APK to Google's play console, I get an optimization notification:

**Your Production APK needs to meet the following criteria:
Your APK should include custom drawables assets for common tablet screen densities.**

Doing some digging, it seems that the reason for this might be because there is no "xxxhdpi" 192x192 icon supplied with the APK.

There is no option in the recently released Delphi 10.3 to supply an xxxhdpi image for the icon, is there a work-around for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to manually add 192x192 pix icon to Android deployment.

Make sure that *Remote Name* is `ic_launcher.png` and that *Remote Path* is `res\drawable-xxxhdpi\`

Android will automatically load use appropriate icon depending on the device.

[image]